# Security of window.postMessage on Chrome Extensions

Tags: security, google-chrome-extension, postmessage

Official Docs recommends to use windows.postMessage to communicate between the content script and local page script:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication

```
document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click",
    function() {
  window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "*");
}, false);
```

But from MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

It says is not recommended to use "*" as the target, and also that "source" is not defined when receiven the message from some extension (and the original docs are using source to detect if it's the current window who is sending the message)

I'm a bit confused about this, is a good practice to use window.postMessage to communicate between the content script and the local page scripts?
And if yes, what is a safe way to do it?

Comment: There's no safe way: once your code runs inside the page it's just like any other page script. Theoretically browsers could implement an internal flag to identify own injected code but they didn't, probably because it's not easy, but also maybe because no one suggested that.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes I know, but at least the safest way, because MDN recommends to not use "*" and says source will be null in Chrome Extensions, but official Docs is using "*" and detecting the window using the source property, is a bit confusing. (Also right now I'm communicating the content and local script using DOM modifications, not window.postMessage)